# Regarding DAX formula to format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax

I have a column with different phases like, Primary, Secondary, Deem Primary,Deem Secondary. I would like to create another column which will use formula to consider Primary and Deem primary as "Primary" and Deem Secondary and Secondary as "Secondary". Below is the example i'm trying to achieve with the formula

```
Column Phase             New Column should show data of column phase as
Deem Primary               Primary
Primary                    Primary
Primary                    Primary  
Deem Primary               Primary
Secondary                  Secondary
Deem Secondary             Secondary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a switch:

```
=SWITCH(A2, "Deem Primary", "Primary", "Deem Secondary", "Secondary", A2)
```

This replaced "Deem Primary" with "Primary" and "Deem Secondary" with "Secondary" and otherwise returns the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that your column is **A** and row where the data starts is **2**:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,"Primary")),"Primary",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,"Secondary")),"Secondary", ""))
```

Presuming that your `New Column` is **B**: copy the above formula in **B2** and then copy it down

> NOTE: formula doesn't cater for rows where there is no value in column **A**